# Docker container works, but fails when build from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an application with 3 containers:
client - an angular application,
gateway - a .NET Core application,
api - a .NET Core application

I am having trouble with the container hosting the angular application.
Here is my Docker file:

```
#stage 1
FROM node:alpine as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/caliber_client /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

and here is the docker compose file:

```
# Please refer https://aka.ms/HTTPSinContainer on how to setup an https developer certificate for your ASP .NET Core service.

version: '3.4'

services:
  calibergateway:
    image: calibergateway
    container_name: caliber-gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: caliber_gateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    networks:
      - caliber-local

  caliberapi:
    image: caliberapi
    container_name: caliber-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: caliber_api/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    networks:
      - caliber-local

  caliberclient:
    image: caliber-client-image
    container_name: caliber-client
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: caliber_client/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7005:7005
    networks:
      - caliber-local

networks:
  caliber-local:
    external: true
```

When I build and run the angular container independently, I can connect and run the site, however if I try to build it with docker-compose, I get the following error:

```
enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
```

I can see that npm cannot find the package.json, but I am copying the whole site to the /app directory in the docker file, so I am not sure where the disconnect is.

Thank you.

Comment: Relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file, where is `package.json`?  Is it in the same directory, or in one of the subdirectories containing a `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @DavidMaze the package.json is one level deeper than the docker-compose file.  It is at the same level of the Dockerfile in the caliber_client folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Dockerfile, the left-hand side of `COPY` statements is always interpreted relative to the `build: { context: }` directory in the `docker-compose.yml` file (or the `build:` directory if there's not a nested argument, or the `docker build` directory argument; but in any case never anything outside this directory tree).

In a comment, you say

> The `package.json` is one level deeper than the `docker-compose.yml` file. It is at the same level of the `Dockerfile` in the `caliber_client` folder.

Assuming that client application is self-contained, you can change the build definition to use the client subdirectory as the build context

```yaml
build:
  context: caliber_client
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

or, since `dockerfile: Dockerfile` is the default, the shorter

```yaml
build: caliber_client
```

If it's important to you to use the parent directory as the build context (maybe you're including some shared files that you don't show in the question) then you can also change the Dockerfile to refer to the subdirectory.

```sh
# when the build: { context: } is the parent directory of this one
COPY caliber_client .
```

Comment: Thank you David.  Changing the context did the trick.